# What does CSS max-width and calc() really do here?

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand what ***calc()*** and ***max-width*** really does here.
From what I've read from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), it takes single expression parameter,
and calculates that value.

So For example, If I were to make a website, let's say my window width is now at **2200px**.

```
max-width: calc(1600px+10%);
margin: 0 auto;
padding-left: 5%;
padding-right: 5%;
```

From what I've understand, my max-width should be

> 1600 + 2200 * 10% = 1600 + 220 = **1820**

so resulting

- padding-left: 5% = 1820 * 5% = **91px**
- padding-right: 5% = 1820 * 5% = **91px**
- element size: 1820 - both padding(182) = **1638px**
- margin-left,right: **190px each**

But when I open the website from this code, it gives me,

- padding-left: **99.361px**
- padding-right: **99.361px**
- element-width: **1599.998px**
- margin-left,right: **94.276px each**

Why does it show different value than I expected? 
What does 10% in calc reference in size when they calculate 10%?

Comment: By `calc(1600+10%)`, do you mean `calc(1600px+10%)`? Since width without a unit is invalid.

Comment: @HaoWu Yes, I just fixed it, it's with 1600px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're getting the values from dev tools.
`padding` is calculated using the parent's size, so `5% padding` would actually be `2200 * 5% = 110`.

Secondly, the element width doesn't include margins or padding, so 1820 would be the size of the element excluding the padding.

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3kzrf1b/)

As you can see from the image below, with a parent width of ~2200px (I had to zoom out, so it's not exactly 2200), everything is sized correctly. Make sure there aren't any other rules that are modifying the element.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure width excludes padding? Margin for sure, but I don't think padding.

Comment: @SydneyY Yep, width always excludes padding (except maybe some discrete old browser). If you look at the image provided above, you can see that the element's width is within the blue rectangle, and then padding (green) is then added onto the width.

Comment: Yep, you're sure https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp